# How to cut a part from a path

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

i get a path from app.getPath()
This path ends in the insalled version with ...\resurces\app.asar

how can i cut that \app.asar away?
I tried it with .replace(/app.asar/,'') but that dosnet work

Comment: `.pelace(/app.asar/,')` is _never_ going to work...

Comment: Oh sorry in the code it's written correct

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Mozillas documentation regarding [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

And then try this:

```
let path = "/resurces/\app.asar";
let end = path.split(/\//g).pop();

console.log('splitted path', path.split(/\//g)); // splitted path ["", "resurces", "app.asar"]
console.log('end̈́', end); // end app.asar
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this not an exact answer to your question, you may also get the needed path directly by using:

```
process.resourcesPath
```

Comment: I switched from saving the data locally to save them in the web. But thanks for your Answers. I ceep them in mind for a future project.